# How to make custom rounding function in my situation?

Tags: ms-access, vba, rounding

I have a table that has 4 time fields `Time1` to `Time4` and after that, I have another field that calculates total hours by subtracting `Time4 - Time1 = Real Hours`.

After that calculation, I want to make a rounding every number by 30 minutes, for example:

1. `2:30` should stay as it is.
2. `1:14` I want to round this up to 30 means `1:30`.
3. `1:41` I want to round this up to 2 means `2:00`.

Minutes below 30 round to 30 except 00, and greater than 30 to 1 hour except 30.

How can I make something like that possible? Is there any built-in ms-access function that can do that?

I hope that I explained well!

**My Table & Examples**

[image: My Table & Examples 1]

I've tried this way but not working at all:

[image: Tried this way but NOt working at all]

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
Public Function RoundTimeUp( _
    ByVal datDate As Date) _
    As Date

    Const cintMult As Integer = 48 '30 minute round
    'Const cintMult As Integer = 96 '15 minute round
    'Const cintMult As Integer = 144 '10 minute round
    'Const cintMult As Integer = 288 '5 minute round
  
    RoundTimeUp = CDate(-Int(CDec(-datDate * cintMult)) / cintMult)

End Function
```

**Addendum**

If numeric values of the time values can be *negative*, values will appear as being rounded *down*. To prevent this, use *Abs*:

```
EX44Abs: RoundTimeUp(Abs([TimeField]))
```

[image: Result values]

*Val0341* holds the constant: `CDbl(#03:41:00#)`

*ValStAuf* shows the numeric values.

*EX44* shows the rounded time without *Abs*, *EX44Abs* the rounded time using *Abs*.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Can i add to the expression builder directly or i have to make a module first ?

Comment: I like your use of `-Int(- ...)` as a simple method to round up as opposed to down. My only suggestion might be to allow the rounding multiple to be supplied as an argument specifying the number of minutes, with the multiple then calculated as `1440/minutes`

Comment: Copy-paste the function into a module, compile, and save. The you can use the function as any other in a _query_. Refrain from using calculated fields; it is a dead end.

Comment: i have created an module, compile it then save it, and i have created a query as below: Result: RoundTimeUp([Real Hours]). but when i want to see the datasheet i will get this error [ Undefined function 'RoundTimeUp' in expression.], could you please help me to solve this error. Really appreciate your help :).

Comment: If you successfully have done so, you can press `Ctrl+G` and type `? RoundTimeUp(Now)`, press `Enter`, and receive an output.

Comment: I have followed exactly your instruction, an Error window popup and say [Compile error: Expected variable or procedure, not module], i don't know what i did wrong i have exactly copy pasted you code :(.

Comment: Sounds like you have given the module the same name as the function. If so, rename the module.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooo much :).

Comment: but i have found a small problem when the hour is at sharp 3:00 hour for example the function will changed to 3:30, How can i solve that to stay at 3:00 ?

Comment: It will not. `RoundTimeUp(#03:00#)` returns `03:00:00`. But your time value may not be "clean"; the addition of the tiniest fraction of second will cause the result to be rounded up. So, check carefully how the time values have been generated.

Comment: Thanks again you are absolutely right i have changed the format to short time and now it's working, buts still when the clock is at sharp 30 it will changed to 1 hour. for example when i write 3:30 the output is 4:00 but i wanna 3:30 stay the same.

Comment: You are right. That's because of the floating point errors introduced by multiplying/dividing _Double_ (the underlying data type of _DateTime_). That can be avoided by converting to _Decimal_. See edited answer, please.

Comment: I have updated the code but still not have the right result, any in put over 30 will come down to 30 for instance 3:59 it will chnage to 3:30, any i dea what i did wrong the query or my table ? i have explaned that i have Four times what i did i have T4-T1 and then re using this data in a query with your rounding function,

Comment: i have uploaded the project to dropbox if you could take a look i will really appreciate that. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/zdp55b7ogcmzwpg/AABhes8QMnRWd5HC90vb8v0Fa?dl=0

Comment: That's because you have numeric negative time values. To handle this, see addendum to answer, please.

Comment: Thanks your are right now, everything works as it should be.

Comment: i have marked as answered, but i have one more problem please now i made a form and i want to calculate a money field to the rounding time [in Euro]*[rounding 2], but i will get a #Name?. do you have any idea why this happen ?

Comment: Ideed. The function is for date/time only. For _rounding numeric values_, go to my article [Rounding values up, down, by 4/5, or to significant figures](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/20299/Rounding-values-up-down-by-4-5-or-to-significant-figures.html) for truly reliably rounding.

Comment: i have read the article but i did not understand it, how can i use it in my situation, now when i want calculate any number to the rounding Time i get "#Name?", i have tried to do the calculation in the query i will get a weird result like for example : 3:00*10 it should be 30$ but i get 1.25, another example 2:30*75$ should be 187,5$ but i get 10.9375. Thanks for your help i really really appreciate :).

Comment: i have found this article and i apply to my query now it's working just fine and the results are correct. thanks again for your help :).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.